# Using AND operator inside JSX block of code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In one of the React function component code, I see the following;

```
const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false);

{fetched && (
            <Table
              states={states}
            />
          )}
```

Now my question is if this is some kind of commonly used pattern where it seems like only if "fetched" is true, does it go to the second expression and render the Table component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Just as you can assign a value to a variables if another variable is falsy, in the following case, assuming that `falsyValue` is falsy (null, undefined...) the OR operator will catch that as false, but because "this value instead" is a truthy value then that's the value that will be assigned.

On the other hand, if `falsyValue` is truthy, then because there's an OR operator there's no need to continue (given that only 1 value has to be true) so the value that `falsyValue` contains will be assigned to `value`.

```
const value = falsyValue || "this value instead"
```

You can also do

```
isValid && myFunction()
```

`myFunction` will only be executed if `isValid` is true

same goes for JSX,

```
return (
  <div>
    {fetched && (
      <Table
        states={states}
      />
    )}
  </div>
)
```

This will return an empty `<div></div>` unless `fetched` is true/truthy

Comment: Great...thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation....Just one last question...What is the effect when fetched is true on the rendering for "fetched" itself....meaning would it not render like string "true" as well to the DOM ?

Comment: @testndtv no, it's performing a AND operation, it's evaluating the first term, if it's false it won't bother going to the second term but if it's true it will go to the second term and because the second term is JSX, that's what will be return, the value "True"/"false" won't be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is exactly true and it's very common pattern in JSX. It's based around how `&&` works.

This operator evaluates the first operand using `ToBoolean`:

- if the first operand is evaluated as `false`, this operand is returned
- if the first operand is evaluated as `true`, the second operand is returned

Yes exactly, `&&` does NOT return boolean values. It returns one of it's operands. Why this also works in `if` statements as you would expect is because the returned operand is `implicitly coerced` into a boolean value there.

Knowing all this, you can use `&&` operator to conditionally render a piece of JSX by using it as a second operand.

If you are interested in more about this topic, I would recommend:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: I think what you're describing there is a ternary operator `x == y ? "this if true" : "this if false"`

Comment: No, absolutely not: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Citing: "Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they will return a non-Boolean value." so, demanding a refund of downvote on my answer :P

Comment: what you're describing in your bullet points is wrong, if the first expression is True, the second expression is returned, else return the first expression. No refund until fixed! :P

Comment: Ahh correct ! lol, messed the most important information *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is a commonly used pattern and it will not return the JSX Table element unless `fetched` is truthy. The React documentation goes over many ways to have conditional logic in your JSX code: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

Something to note that the other answers did not address is that a value like 0 is falsy, so if it is used with an && operator it will return 0, which is valid JSX element content and it will be rendered so you have to be careful with that.

In this example below, `<div>0</div>` will be rendered by the render method:

```
render() {
    const count = 0;  
    return (
        <div>
            { count && <h1>Messages: {count}</h1> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

The falsy values of `0` & `NaN` will be rendered as the JSX element's content, but the falsy values of `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `""` will cause nothing to be rendered as the JSX element's content.

Here is a little more information on falsy values in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy.